# Generic ReactiveUserControl "cannot be edited in Design view"

Tags: wpf, xaml, reactiveui

I changed my **UserControl** to be a **ReactiveUserControl** and now I can't view the Design View. Is there anything I can do to get the designer to work with ReactiveUserControl?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Visual Studio designer has issues when your control or window directly inherits from a generic class.  This was a pretty common issue with WinForms as well.  You can work around this issue by defining another non-generic class that sits between the generic `ReactiveUserControl` and your control:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : MyUserControlBase
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public abstract class MyUserControlBase: ReactiveUserControl<MyUserControlViewModel>
{
}
```

In the XAML, our root object element is defined as the base element (`MyUserControlBase`) and its class declaration is connected to the partial class defined above (`MyUserControl`):

```
<myNameSpace:MyUserControlBase
    x:Class="MyNameSpace.MyUserControl"
    xmlns:myNameSpace="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
```

Comment: Just to add after editing you may get a "The name "MyUserControlBase" does not exist in namespace "clr-namespace:********". Make sure and rebuild project after changes.